# Updating RecordType Id - importing data

Tags: data-loader, record-type

I have exported data from production in .csv file, now I'm trying to import data  to sandbox and I'm running into issue where RecordType.Id is not same as in the sandbox.

How should you go after correcting this? is there any tool to use? some says use vlookup to map and some says copy the production recordtype.id and update the same to sandbox recordtype.id.

Any suggestions?

`select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Canada' and SobjectType = 'employee__c' limit 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update `RecordType.Id` in any Sandbox to match that to Production. It’s the `Id` field and is not updatable as any other System (Id) fields.

You will need to replace the `RecordType.Id` to match that with Sandbox. As for tools, you can use VLOOKUP in Excel to do so. If you are using an ETL tool, the tool can transform the values for you.

If you can use SFDX CLI along with Bulk API, you can actually utilize the Record Type Name only to load data without the need of specifying any Id. Refer to [this answer from sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250043/54851) for implementation details.